# Convert string into datetime.time object

Tags: python, time, python-datetime

Given the `string` in this format `"HH:MM"`, for example `"03:55"`, that represents *3 hours and 55 minutes*.

I want to convert it to `datetime.time` object for easier manipulation. What would be the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and call [`.time()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) on the result:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('03:55', '%H:%M').time()
datetime.time(3, 55)
```

The first argument to `.strptime()` is the string to parse, the second is the expected format.

Comment: I have an issue where `strptime` assumes a date when using this method.

Comment: @user4933: `strptime()` doesn't assume anything. It doesn't guess, it doesn't have heuristics. It can only parse strings that match the exact format you give it. If you have unexpected output you need to fix your use of the method call.

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> datetime.time(*map(int, '03:55'.split(':')))
datetime.time(3, 55)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is perhaps less clear to future readers, but the `*map` method is more than 10 times faster. See below and make an informed decision in your code. If calling this check many times and speed matters, go with the generator ("map").

```
In [31]: timeit(datetime.strptime('15:00', '%H:%M').time())
7.76 µs ± 111 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


In [28]: timeit(dtime(*map(int, SHUTDOWN_AT.split(':'))))
696 ns ± 11.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply load if as `iso`:

```py
>>> from datetime import time
>>> time.fromisoformat("03:55")
datetime.time(3, 55)
```