# Converting str to datetime. time

Tags: python

I have a string in the `str` format

```
 PATTERN_OUT = "%H:%M"
date_time = (datetime.strftime(enddateandtime, PATTERN_OUT))
```

I need to convert it to `datetime.time`. How can this be done?

Comment: Please show `enddateandtime` in your question.

Comment: enddateandtime = 2021-06-09 06:19:00+03:00 date_time=06:19

Comment: by using `strptime` and `time` such as suggested here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295673/convert-string-into-datetime-time-object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the fact that time string is `\d\d:\d\d`.
Look at the following snippet.

```py
from datetime import time
time_str = "10:01"
time(*map(int, time_str.split(':')))
```

Add exception handler if required.