# How to add an input numbers on dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, time, type-conversion

I'm new to python. I tried different ways to add values to my code. In this code, I have 2 problem.

- I need to ***use the input numbers*** (e.g 0400 or 0352) ***to add to the dictionary***
- ***convert*** the input numbers to ***time*** (e.g 4:00 or 3:52).

> ```
> employee1_data = {};
>     
> def login_time_admin_a():  
>         while True:
>             print("""
>             ==============================
>             | PLEASE ENTER YOUR INFO     |
>             ==============================
>                 """)
>             time=input("ENTER TIME: ")
>             if time.isalpha():
>                 print("""
>                 ======================
>                 | INCORRECT INPUT    |
>                 ======================
>                 """)
>                 continue
>             date = input("ENTER DATE: ")
>             if date.isalpha():
>                 print("""
>                 ======================
>                 |  INCORRECT INPUT   |
>                 ======================
>                 """)
>                 continue
>             else:
>                 print("""
>                     ============================
>                     | THANK YOU FOR LOGGING IN |
>                     ============================
>                     """)
>                 employee1_data[time] = time()
>                 employee1_data[date] = date()
> ```

Comment: What exact problem do you face ? You can't input a string then "call" it with `time()` Seems the problem is NOT at all adding in dict, but converting frmo string to date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string into datetime.time object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295673/convert-string-into-datetime-time-object)

Answer (score 0):

According with [the documenatation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> employee1_data = {}
>>> employee1_data['this_key_001']='this_value_001'
>>> print(employee1_data['this_key_001'])
this_value_001
>>> employee1_data['use the input numbers']=int('0400')
>>> print(employee1_data['use the input numbers'])
400
>>> employee1_data['use the input numbers']=str('0400')
>>> print(employee1_data['use the input numbers'])
0400
```

You can use the same method for the time data or you can use a special format data or string ...

```
data = (1)
format_string = "Your current balance is $%s."
print(format_string % data)
...
Your current balance is $1.
```